# How can I match columns in two different tables and output selected columns to a third table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-workbench

I currently have three tables in MySQL where I would like to have UPC values that match in the first two tables output the other contents in table 2 to table 3. I made the tables below as to how I would want them to output.

```
Table 1
|-------------------|
|        UPC        |                  
|-------------------|
|    123456789851   |
|-------------------|
|    123456789789   |
|-------------------|
|    123456789765   |
|-------------------|

Table 2
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|                  
|        UPC        |     Shelf    |    Isle    |    ItemName   |                  
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|                  
|    123456789851   |       C      |     1      |     Eggs      |                 
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|                  
|    123456789789   |       A      |     1      |     Milk      |                 
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|                  
|    123456789765   |       D      |     2      |     Coffee    |                 
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|                  
|    123456789582   |       A      |     5      | Apple Juice   |                 
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|                 
|    123456789542   |       S      |     2      |     Cereal    |                 
|-------------------|--------------|------------|---------------|
```

If UPC from Table 1 matches UPC in Table 2 output to Table 3 everything except UPC

```
Table 3
    |--------------|------------|---------------|                  
    |     Shelf    |    Isle    |    ItemName   |                  
    |--------------|------------|---------------|                  
    |       C      |     1      |     Eggs      |                 
    |--------------|------------|---------------|                  
    |       A      |     1      |     Milk      |                 
    |--------------|------------|---------------|                  
    |       D      |     2      |     Coffee    |                 
    |--------------|------------|---------------|
```

Comment: You have should your tables and your expected result.  You haven't shown your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Join `Table1` to `Table2` so you can insert the matching rows:

```
INSERT INTO Table3(Shelf, Isle, ItemName)
SELECT t2.Shelf, t2.Isle, t2.ItemName
FROM Table2 t2 INNER JOIN Table1 t1
ON t1.UPC = t2.UPC
```

or with `EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO Table3(Shelf, Isle, ItemName)
SELECT t2.Shelf, t2.Isle, t2.ItemName
FROM Table2 t2 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.UPC = t2.UPC)
```